# Is it possible the preselect a cell in Primefaces DataTable component?

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, selection

is it possible to preselect a cell in the Primefaces DataTable component? How do I do that? Tried it already with a Primefaces Cell object with a Getter, but this is not called by my data table :-(.
I need this because I have to restore the selection of the cell done a request before, if validation tells me, that a required field in the form was not filled.

This is my xhtml code snippet:

```
    <p:dataTable id="select-start-pos" var="item"
        selectionMode="singlecell"
        value="#{frankingController.startposItems}" 
        selection="#{frankingController.selectedCell}"
        styleClass="startPosGrid">
      <p:column id="startposcol1">
        <h:outputText value=""/>
      </p:column>
      <p:column id="startposcol2" rendered="#{frankingController.startposColumns > 1}">
        <h:outputText value=""/>    
      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Thank you for your help!
Mike

Comment: No and 3.x doesn't have cell selection feature.

Comment: @Cagatay: if that's a fact which can not be "workarounded" in any way, then you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and 3.x doesn't have cell selection feature

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sheet control instead of Datatable, it has row selection feature.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/sheet.jsf